How to wait for a react component to be FULLY RENDERED AND PAINTED? And while rendering display a loading screen?
Edited question, now that I understand the difference between DOM RENDER and DOM PAINTING.
I understand that the DOM (Document Object Model) could be a thing that is rendered or painted.
I also understand, the DOM (Document Object Model) could be a thing that receives the data regarding the application rendering and painting.

What I really want, is to wait for the DOM to be FULLY RENDERED AND PAINTED before showing it. While the application is being rendered and painted, I want to display a loading screen.
The component in question which I need to wait for its RENDERING AND PAINT is a form component, that uses a video and 3 images. I want to wait the DOM TO BE FULLY RENDERED, which means, the HTML/CSS structure of my web application and also wait for it to be FULLY PAINTED AND VISIBLE, in manner, that you cannot see the process of the PAINTING happening on the screen.

Things I have tried:
Lazy Loading:
const Footer = lazy(() => import('./componentes/Footer'))


However, lazy loading has nothing to do with RENDER, and much less with PAINTING (AS FAR AS I HAVE UNDERSTOOD! I COULD BE WRONG).
Therefore, it wouldn't help me with my question.
The second thing I have tried is using "useEffect" on my components.
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
setLoading(false);
}, []);

However, as far as I have understood, use Effect waits for the component to be rendered before executed, therefore, it doesn't wait for the painting to occur.
I need to wait for the DOM PAINTING before showing the screen. and While the RENDERING AND PAINTING OCCURS, a Loading screen should appear. How would I be able to do this?

The React components must be rendered first before they are flushed to the DOM and painted to the screen. Can you [edit] to clarify the issue/problem in better detail?

If you need the video and images to be fully loaded (which is not related to rendering and painting), you would need to listen to their onload events before hiding your loading screen.

So, painting has nothing to do with the process of the images being shown on the screen? right? So, just to be sure, rendering would be the creation of html and css by the  the js, the painting would be the presence or not of this components on the website, right? Then, the images, would be called to be shown only after the html/css structure is set, therefore, they wouldn't be part of the painting process, right?
